# RDLC: show child collection data without using subreports

Tags: rdlc

i'm trying to create a RDCL report with the follow requirements:

- The datasource is a master business object that also has a child business object.
- I want to show some data of the master BO using a List.
- I want to show the details of the child BO using a Table.
- I do not want to use subreports.
- I do not want to flatten my object graph and use grouping

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure you can achieve what you're looking for. Either you must use subreports or by definition of master-child data you must use grouping.

I know this answer comes on late but this post still shows on search results and it has 1K views.

Hope this helps!